# Unfortunately App Has Stopped When using AsyncTask

Tags: android-asynctask, crash

I've been working on a sales app for my coworkers. I've been taking it a step at a time by making an server application that reads a txt file on my computer, then sends it to an app on an android phone, which displays the results. The problem is that the app on the phone crashes once the asyncTask finishes and both the server and phone app terminate. I've looked at the logcat, and It appears to be a nullpointer exception. I find this weird, as the while loops in my code are supposed to only allow non-null data to get through. 
Here's my code:

```
package com.AWSbeacon;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.AWSbeacon.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    String[] Names = null;
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button starter = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        starter.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            new GetNames().execute();
            Names = names.toArray(Names); //the error pops up here  
            for(int i=0; i<Names.length; i++){
                TextView txtView1 = (TextView)findViewById((int) R.id.text1);
                txtView1.setText((CharSequence)txtView1 + Names[i]);
            }
            }
            });
        }

 class GetNames extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{


        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
        String[] Names = null;
        DataOutputStream out = null;
        DataInputStream in = null;
                Socket sock = null;
            String  T = null;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                try {
                    sock = new Socket("elvishknight1.noip.me", 8000);
                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    in = new DataInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                 out = new DataOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            try {
                while(true){
                out.writeUTF("ok");
                T = in.readUTF();
                if(in!=null && !in.readUTF().contains("end")){
                names.add(T);
                }
                else if(in.readUTF().contains("end")){
                    break;
                }
            }

                out.flush();
                out.close();
                in.close();
                sock.close();


            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                return null; 

        }
    }
```

My server code(just in case):

```
package beaconserver;

import java.io.*;


import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Bserver {

 static BufferedReader text = null; 
 static ServerSocket Sock = null;
 static Socket server = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<String> Names = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        text = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/home/kyle/Documents/names.txt"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     try {

        String names = text.readLine();
        while((names=text.readLine())!=null){
          Names.add(names);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     String[] Text = new String[Names.size()];
     Text = Names.toArray(Text);
        SendMessage(Text);
    }

    public static void SendMessage(String[] lines){
        DataInputStream in = null;
        DataOutputStream out = null;
        String ok = null;
        try {
            Sock = new ServerSocket(8000);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try{
            server = Sock.accept();
                in = new DataInputStream(server.getInputStream());
                out = new DataOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());

                for(int i=0; i<lines.length; i++){
                    while(ok==null){
                     ok = in.readUTF();
                        if(ok!=null){
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    out.writeUTF(lines[i]);
                }
                out.writeUTF("end");
            in.close();
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            server.close();
            Sock.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

as well as the logcat:

```
05-25 09:23:37.218: E/AndroidRuntime(9722): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-25 09:23:37.218: E/AndroidRuntime(9722): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-25 09:23:37.218: E/AndroidRuntime(9722):     at java.util.ArrayList.toArray(ArrayList.java:514)
05-25 09:23:37.218: E/AndroidRuntime(9722):     at com.AWSbeacon.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:37)
05-25 09:23:37.218: E/AndroidRuntime(9722):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
05-25 09:23:37.218: E/AndroidRuntime(9722):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
05-25 09:23:37.218: E/AndroidRuntime(9722):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
05-25 09:23:37.218: E/AndroidRuntime(9722):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-25 09:23:37.218: E/AndroidRuntime(9722):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-25 09:23:37.218: E/AndroidRuntime(9722):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
05-25 09:23:37.218: E/AndroidRuntime(9722):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-25 09:23:37.218: E/AndroidRuntime(9722):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-25 09:23:37.218: E/AndroidRuntime(9722):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-25 09:23:37.218: E/AndroidRuntime(9722):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-25 09:23:37.218: E/AndroidRuntime(9722):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

You use the wrong names variable in tour onClickListener.
Maybe you should think about renaming some of your variables e.g. use `nameArray`